# UITableView within a UITableViewCell is not selectable by VoiceOver

Tags: ios, uitableview, uikit, voiceover, uiaccessibility

The `UITableViewCell`s of my `UITableView` each contain their own table view with just one cell.

VoiceOver works fine selecting the cells of the main table view, but I can't figure out how to make the inner cells/table view selectable by VoiceOver.

Does anyone know how to make a `UITableView` inside of a `UITableViewCell` selectable by VoiceOver?

Comment: Couple notes... first, *"not ideal, but requirements"* ... sometimes we need to change the requirements. *"on button tap, phone needs to sprout wings and fly across the room"* may be a fine requirement, but not necessarily doable. Not saying your "cell in a table in a cell in a table" **cannot** be done, but maybe it needs to be justified. What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: Essentially what I'm trying to do is have a button within the cell, but that responds to user input like a UITableViewCell. As a UIButton would capture any touch down and prevent scrolling, and also has a slightly different highlight effect.

Comment: I guess I would need to see an example to understand the need for your structure... I haven't done any work with VoiceOver / accessibility, but this answer (and its contained links) may be helpful - https://stackoverflow.com/a/57372335/6257435

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [UIAccessibilityCustomAction](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiaccessibilitycustomaction) to select the inner cell by assigning each with a selector.

```
UIAccessibilityCustomAction(
    name: "Call",
    target: self,
    selector: #selector(activateCallButton) // Your inner cell name
),
UIAccessibilityCustomAction(
    name: "Open address in Maps",
    target: self,
    selector: #selector(activateLocationButton)
)
```

Reference - [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accessibility/supporting_voiceover_in_your_app)

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Nikulsinh, but unfortunately while that makes it possible to selection the action the inner cell performs, it doesn't make the inner cell itself selectable by VoiceOver. As in, it doesn't make it possible to tap on the inner cell to select it.

Comment: Okie I thought you wanted to perform its action. There must be some help in the link of docs I mentioned. There where many different methods and ways for VoiceOver accessibility.

Answer (score 0):

as an alternative approach, if you can place each section (the specific cell you are referring to for e.g. table view and a button) *inside their own containers*, this allows Voice Over users to easily navigate between the various cells using the containers (plus any navigation like rotor).

Now you can do this by giving the containing view of the specific cell (of the example of button and the table view each) an `accessibilityContainerType` of `UIAccessibilityContainerTypeSemanticGroup` then your VoiceOver should work